# run sql script from shell script

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the below shell script that calls an sql script. The problem is it calls the sql script, i enter the username,password ,dbname  and after that it creates the table
but it doesn't exit from the sql prompt.

### test.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh


sql_test=test.sql

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus /nolog @${sql_test}

exit
```

### test.sql

```
CONNECT &&usr/&&password@&&dbname


CREATE TABLE report1
(
    product_code                       VARCHAR2(30)
  , test_inc                           NUMBER(20,2)

);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could use a HERE document to eliminate the need to put the exit command into the SQL file:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus /nolog << HERE
@${sql_test};
exit sql.sqlcode
HERE
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't you also put an exit statement in test.sql ?

Comment: EXIT is exactly what is needed.